# Is it possible to make a hybrid K8S cluster AWS / Raspberry PI

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, raspberry-pi

I have a classic K8S cluster using AWS.

Now, I also have 8 differents ARM boards, all have 1GB in ram.

I have a 3 Raspberry Pi 2, 1 Raspberry 3B+, and 4 Samsung Artik.

Is it possible to add them to my existing K8S cluster ? How should I do it ?

PD: I used [Kops](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kops/) to install my K8S cluster on Kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with RKE, but KOPS is built for deploying a k8s cluster in AWS. It is not built for expanding to bare metal outside of AWS